# How to break apart text in individual words or letters in Illustrator cs6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

Hi all does anybody know how to break text in words or letters. So that they can be editable **individually as text not Path** ?

Answer (score 5):

I have found an answer on another forum.  I work in motion graphics and create scenes in Illustrator with a lot of typography.  In order for the vectors to be individually animated I need the word(s) (still editable in case the client wants any changes) on a separate layer.  This is a very annoying and tedious process but I have found a fairly quick workaround.

Save your Illustrator file as a PDF and Uncheck the Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities box.  Close the file.  Now once you re-open the PDF within Illustrator the text will be broken into groups depending on your layout, color, text size (and it will remain editable).

For me this is way faster than duplicating my text layer, deleting the words I don't need, and re-aligning to my design for each word I need to separate.

Comment: I tried this and all it does is break the text into lines of editable text. Not the individual letters or words. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: can't up-vote this enough....

Answer (score 3):

If you have a short text like logo, the simplest way is to use Type tool for every letter creating different object to every letter.

The second way, is to use a [free script divide text frame](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/divideTextFrame.js).

Also, take a look at [this script](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3510986#3510986), I paste one of the versions here for the case of "broken link", however there are some other version - in the comments they wrote the scripts worked worked.

```
//  script.description = splits selected texFrame into separate characters;  
//  script.required = select a point text textFrame before running;  
//  script.parent = CarlosCanto;  // 3/5/11  
//  script.elegant = false;  

var idoc = app.activeDocument;  
var tWord = idoc.selection[0];  
var xpos = tWord.position[0];  
var ypos = tWord.position[1];  
var charCount = tWord.characters.length;  

for (i=charCount-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)  
     {  
          var ichar = tWord.duplicate();  
          ichar.contents = tWord.characters[i].contents;  
          tWord.characters[i].remove();  
          var width = tWord.width;  
          ichar.position = [xpos+width,ypos];  
     }  
tWord.remove();
```

Comment: This is almost close to what i want. But I want to break sleeted text in to words and some times in letters to. For example "Hello how are you?" this should be break in to different frame of "Hello" "how" "are" "you?"
Can this script editable for this options?

Comment: @GobindNeupane on the page provided there are some versions of the scripts - contact the author (he looks friendly), probably he will add some iteration for Space character breaking the text to separate words....